# Calculate x ^ y in O(log n)

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

Interview question:

> Calculate x ^ y in O(log n)

There are different answers like "Use the Indian Power algorithm" or

```
double power(double x, int y) 
{
    if(y == 0) return 1;

    double d = power(x, y/2);

    if(y%2 == 0) return d*d;
    else return x*d*d;
}
```

1. is it a correct answer?
2. is there any better way of writing a code for this question?

Comment: no it's an interview question you can see the tag ;)

Comment: else is redundant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called [Exponentiation by Squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). As far as implementation goes, it is a matter of taste. Your recursive implementation is good, but non-recursive implementations (from the link above) may look a little cleaner to people who do not like recursion or erroneously believe that it is somehow "wasteful" or "slow".

Answer (score 3):

Questions about basic mathematical operations, and questions about computational complexity, are usually answered quickly by Wikipedia.

[Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation): [Efficient computation of integral powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_of_integer_powers)

> In general, the number of multiplication operations required to compute bn can be reduced to Θ(log n) by using exponentiation by squaring or (more generally) addition-chain exponentiation. Finding the minimal sequence of multiplications (the minimal-length addition chain for the exponent) is a difficult problem for which no efficient algorithms are currently known (see Subset sum problem), but many reasonably efficient heuristic algorithms are available.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way to do it:

let's say you wanna to 2^1024, that would take ... wait for it ... 11 multiplications

you do it this way

```
2*2 = 2^2
2^2 * 2^2 = 2^4
2^4 * 2^4 = 2^8
2^8 * 2^8 = 2^16
....
2^512 * 2^512 = 2^1024
```

so basically, you only need to write your exponent in base 2 and get all the relevant multiplications

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyse it:

`power` is called (via recursion) as many times as the original `y` is divisible by 2 (that is the largest number, `k`, such that `2^k < y`). This means that the number of calculations is roughly `k=log_2(2^k)=log_2(y)~=log(y)`, so it is a correct answer.

The answer to the "better way" depends on what counts as "better"

Answer (score -1):

Here is much faster: `%` is a very expensive operation, replacing it with a bitwise operation is a tremendous savings; also replace `y/2` with `y>>1`:

```
double power(double x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) return 1;

    double d = power(x, y>>1);

    if((y&1) == 0) return d*d;
    else return x*d*d;
}
```

Comment: -1. Did you verify the performance improvement by profiling? `x%2` is universally optimized to `x&1`, and likewise with `x/2` and `x>>1`. Microoptimizations are not a good idea unless you're solving a problem discovered by actually reading the disassembly. All this accomplishes is to use the wrong operators for the job, making the precedence rules even more screwy. For example, `(y&1 == 0)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: While I totally agree with @Potatoswatter, I would like to add that `if(y&1)` is also possible (despite bad in some code styles) :D

Comment: On the other hand, in some contexts, writing `>> 1` is more obvious than `/ 2` and even has distinct semantics, e.g. in PHP where `/` does float division and `>> 1` casts the operands to integers.